# Encoded character breaks Knockout js data bind on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockout.js, internet-explorer-8, javascript-databinding

I'm having a very strange issue on IE8 (and only on IE version lower than 8). The problem is in attr binding, if I put encoded email string (with %26, %40 and etc.) the page won't render the data binds in text field ('firstlast@domain.com' in the case below), instead it will render as "mailto:first%26last%40domain.com".

```
<a data-bind="    visible: Email.length > 0, text: 'firstlast@domain.com', attr:{ href: 'mailto:' +  'first%26last%40domain.com' }"></a>
```

The strange thing is it renders just fine if I use the non-encoded string

```
<a data-bind="    visible: Email.length > 0, text: 'firstlast@domain.com', attr:{ href: 'mailto:' +  'first&last@domain.com' }"></a>
```

Both ways work properly on Firefox and Chrome and higher version IE.

Comment: Probably just an IE8 bug, maybe only for locally hosted: http://www.wrensoft.com/forum/showthread.php?3460-IE8-bug(-)-problem-with-URL-encoding-ampersand-character-and-relative-file-paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged through it and found Knockout js is using the DOM method setAttribute() to set href. And per the documentation from W3School, setAttribute() supports browser IE9 and newer, so I think that is what causes the strange result.

I also searched around about the setAttribute(), other people also encountered similar issue, see link below:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/aa6bf9a5-0c0b-4a02-a115-c5b85783ca8c/javascript-modifying-href-changes-link-text-as-well-for-mailto-protocol?forum=iewebdevelopment